# How to debug a kernel panic? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel

So, I have been having kernel panics. My computer will suddenly come off and then a `dmesg` like output shows on the screen. The first two lines read

```
[20352.651631] BUG: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000028
[20352.651667] IP: [<ffffffff8158a7bb>] input_event+0x2b/70
```

And the last two lines

```
[20352.662214] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt.
[20352.662214] drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching to text console
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

I would post directly but it doesn't let me. Also, I can't find the `dmesg` output. I ran

```
sudo grep -nri panic /var/log/
zgrep -ni panic /var/log/dmesg.*.gz
zgrep -ni panic /var/log/kern.log.*.gz
```

All I got was `registered panic notifier` but nothing about the crash.

Anyway, it has happened a few times this past month, and I haven't been doing anything in particular that I can see for this to happen. Usually I'm browsing the web or watching videos or writing up homework and suddenly, crash. Screen goes dark, text output, and I can't do anything until I manually switch the computer off and on.When it comes back on, everything seems to be perfectly normal and it won't crash again for a week or so.

I have also been reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks but I can't make much out of it. I'll go over it with some more detail, but I'd really appreciate some advice on how to get started with the debugging.

**EDIT**

It happened again. I've posted a picture and corrected what it said. I finally have time since it's the weekend. I'll run `memtest` and try to reproduce the panic at home. Just to be clear, my computer boots and works just fine---nothing weird happens that I can notice, until it crashes, that is.

Comment: Have you done a memtest? Also, more complete `dmesg` output would be useful.

Comment: I don't know where to find the full `dmesg` and I've been looking. I'll take a picture next time. I'll run `memtest` overnight tonight. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just type `dmesg` in a terminal. ;)

Comment: `dmesg` resets every time the computer reboots. Will it have info about the crash?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, old `dmesg`s are in `/var/log/dmesg*`.

Comment: I looked at those as well. `grep -ni panic /var/log/dmesg*` returns a line `registered panic notifier` but nothing about the crash. Same for `zgrep -ni panic /var/log/dmesg.*.gz`